# What do I use as hostname for MX records? - Mailgun

Tags: mailgun

Sorry for the newbie question.

On Mailgun docs for MX records, it [doesn't state](https://i.gyazo.com/31cd06a4791700645aa436e481fc03c4.png) what hostname to use.

So I used my [default domain name](https://i.gyazo.com/3a52cd6cea7be3376339fb6aace55129.png), like `example.com`.  But this doesn't seem to work.  My TXT and CNAME records are verified, but my MX records are not.

What should I put as my hostname for verifying the MX records?

Answer (score 4):

I had set my domain to mg.(mydomain).ca.  So it worked after changing the hostname to `mg`.

Answer (score 0):

`@` will allow you to email via `callme@ho.me` rather than `callme@mail.ho.me` or `callme@mg.ho.me`.